# Writing a React higher-order component with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, higher-order-components

I'm writing a [React higher-order component (HOC)](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html) with TypeScript. The HOC should accept one more prop than the wrapped component, so I wrote this:

```
type HocProps {
    // Contains the prop my HOC needs
    thingy: number
}
type Component<P> = React.ComponentClass<P> | React.StatelessComponent<P>
interface ComponentDecorator<TChildProps> {
    (component: Component<TChildProps>): Component<HocProps & TChildProps>;
}
const hoc = function<TChildProps>(): (component: Component<TChildProps>) => Component<HocProps & TChildProps) {
    return (Child: Component<TChildProps>) => {
        class MyHOC extends React.Component<HocProps & TChildProps, void> {
            // Implementation skipped for brevity
        }
        return MyHOC;
    }
}
export default hoc;
```

In other words, `hoc` is a function that yields the actual HOC. This HOC is (I believe) a function that accepts a `Component`. Since I don't know in advance what the wrapped component will be, I'm using a generic type `TChildProps` to define the shape of the props of the wrapped component. The function also returns a `Component`. The returned component accepts props for the wrapped component (again, typed using the generic `TChildProps`) *and* some props it needs for itself (type `HocProps`). When using the returned component, all of the props (both `HocProps` and the props for the wrapped `Component`) should be supplied.

Now, when I attempt to use my HOC, I do the following:

```
// outside parent component
const WrappedChildComponent = hoc()(ChildComponent);

// inside parent component
render() {
    return <WrappedChild
                thingy={ 42 } 
                // Prop `foo` required by ChildComponent
                foo={ 'bar' } />
}
```

But I get a TypeScript error:

```
TS2339: Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & HocProps & {} & { children? ReactNode; }'
```

It seems to me TypeScript is not replacing `TChildProps` with the shape the of the props needed for `ChildComponent`. How can I make TypeScript do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one way to make it work: by invoking the `hoc` with the type argument supplied, like so:

```
import ChildComponent, { Props as ChildComponentProps } from './child';
const WrappedChildComponent = hoc<ChildComponentProps>()(ChildComponent);
```

But I don't really like it. It requires me to export the props of the child (which I'd rather not do) and I have the feeling I'm telling TypeScript something it should be able to infer.

Answer (score 11):

A bit late to the party.
I like to use the Omit TypeScript utility type to solve this issue.
Link to the documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittk

```
import React, {ComponentType} from 'react';

export interface AdditionalProps {
    additionalProp: string;
}

export function hoc<P extends AdditionalProps>(WrappedComponent: ComponentType<P>) : ComponentType<Omit<P, 'additionalProp'>> {
    const additionalProp = //...
    return props => (
        <WrappedComponent
            additionalProp={additionalProp}
            {...props as any}
        />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If what you're asking for is if it's possible to define a HOC that can add a new prop, let's say "thingy", to a component without modifying that component's props definition to include "thingy" I think that's impossible.

That's because at some point in the code you'll end up with:

```
render() {
    return (
        <WrappedComponent thingy={this.props.thingy} {...this.props}/>
    );
}
```

And that will always throw an error if `WrappedComponent` does not include `thingy` in its props definition. The child has to know what it receives. Off hand, I can't think of a reason for passing a prop to a component that doesn't know about to it anyway. You wouldn't be able to reference that prop in the child component without an error.

I think the trick is to define the HOC as a generic around the props of the child and then to just include your prop `thingy` or whatever in that child's interface explicitly.

```
interface HocProps {
    // Contains the prop my HOC needs
    thingy: number;
}

const hoc = function<P extends HocProps>(
    WrappedComponent: new () => React.Component<P, any>
) {
    return class MyHOC extends React.Component<P, any> {
        render() {
            return (
                <WrappedComponent {...this.props}/>
            );
        }
    }
}
export default hoc;

// Example child class

// Need to make sure the Child class includes 'thingy' in its props definition or
// this will throw an error below where we assign `const Child = hoc(ChildClass)`
interface ChildClassProps {
    thingy: number;
}

class ChildClass extends React.Component<ChildClassProps, void> {
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>{this.props.thingy}</h1>
        );
    }
}

const Child = hoc(ChildClass);
```

Now of course this example HOC doesn't really do *anything*. Really HOC's should be doing some sort of logic to provide a value for the child prop. Like for example maybe you have a component that displays some generic data that gets updated repeatedly. You could have different ways it gets updated and create HOC's to separate that logic out.

You have a component:

```
interface ChildComponentProps {
    lastUpdated: number;
    data: any;
}

class ChildComponent extends React.Component<ChildComponentProps, void> {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.props.lastUpdated}</h1>
                <p>{JSON.stringify(this.props.data)}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And then an example HOC that just updates the child component on a fixed interval using `setInterval` might be:

```
interface AutoUpdateProps {
    lastUpdated: number;
}

export function AutoUpdate<P extends AutoUpdateProps>(
    WrappedComponent: new () => React.Component<P, any>,
    updateInterval: number
) {
    return class extends React.Component<P, any> {
        autoUpdateIntervalId: number;
        lastUpdated: number;

        componentWillMount() {
            this.lastUpdated = 0;
            this.autoUpdateIntervalId = setInterval(() => {
                this.lastUpdated = performance.now();
                this.forceUpdate();
            }, updateInterval);
        }

        componentWillUnMount() {
            clearInterval(this.autoUpdateIntervalId);
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <WrappedComponent lastUpdated={this.lastUpdated} {...this.props}/>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Then we could create a component that updates our child once every second like this:

```
const Child = AutoUpdate(ChildComponent, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the following article on Pluralsight to be extremely helpful for understanding HOCs in Typescript and basic concepts of it. All other articles I came across used to be mix and match of thing from here and there, and this just worked, step by step, all clear and concise:

[Link to the article](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/higher-order-composition-typescript-react).

Comment: That's a great article!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `hoc` is generic, but takes no parameters—there’s no data to infer anything from. That forces you to explicitly specify the type for `hoc` when you call it. Even if you do `hoc()(Foo)`, Typescript has to evaluate `hoc()` first—and there’s zero information to go on at that point. Hence needing `hoc<FooProps>()(Foo)`.

If the body of `hoc` doesn’t require the type and can be flexible on that point, you could make `hoc` *not* be generic, but instead *return* a generic function (the higher-order component).

That is, instead of

```
const hoc = function<TChildProps>(): (component: Component<TChildProps>) => Component<HocProps & TChildProps) {
    return (Child: Component<TChildProps>) => {
```

you could instead have

```
const hoc = function(): <TChildProps>(component: Component<TChildProps>) => Component<HocProps & TChildProps) {
    return <TChildProps>(Child: Component<TChildProps>) => {
```

(note the placement of `<TChildProps>`)

Then when you call `hoc()`, you get a generic function, and when you call `hoc()(Foo)`, it will be inferred to be equivalent to `hoc()<FooProps>(Foo)`.

This does not help you if `hoc` itself needs to do something with the type parameter—if it does, you are saying “give me a function that will only accept arguments that are components with this type as a property,” and you need to give it that type *then*. Whether or not this helps depends on what the actual `hoc` function is doing, which isn’t demonstrated in your question.

I assume that your actual use-case *is* doing something in `hoc`, rather than just immediately returning the higher-order component function. Certainly, if not, you should just remove the layer of indirection and have there just be the higher-order component. Even if you *are* doing things inside `hoc`, I would strongly suggest that there is a pretty good chance you are better off just *not* doing that, moving that functionality to within the actual higher-order component, and eliminating the indirection. Your approach only makes sense if you are calling `hoc` once or a few times, but then using the resulting `hoc()` function(s) many, many times with different parameters—and even then, this would be an optimization that may well be premature.