# Understanding React Higher Order Components (HOC) and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, higher-order-components

**Short version**:

Why do I have to import types which I don't use in files which are wrapped by a Higher Order Component in typescript?

---

**Long version**:

While creating a `Higher Order Component` (short `HOC`) in typescript I get the following two typescript errors a lot:

**TS4082**:

```
ERROR in ./A.tsx
error TS4082: Default export of the module has or is using private name 'BProps'.
ERROR in ./B.tsx
error TS4082: Default export of the module has or is using private name 'AProps'.
```

**TS2345**:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Attributes & Props'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'foo' does not exist in type 'Attributes & Props'.
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43680786/writing-a-react-higher-order-component-with-typescript) goes into detail about **how** to work with HOCs but don't help me with the **why**!

Why do I need the imports marked with a comment `// WHY?` in this example? (If I remove either of them I get typescript errors):

*myHoc.tsx*

```
import { AProps } from './A';
import { BProps } from './B';
...

export interface Props { ... }
export interface State { ... }
export interface myHocProps { ... }

export default (Component: React.ComponentType) => {
    return class extends React.Component<Props & AProps & BProps, State> {
        ...
    }
}
```

*A.tsx*

```
import { BProps } from './B';  // WHY?
import withSearch, {
    Props,  // WHY?
    State,  // WHY?
    myHocProps } from './myHoc';
...

export interface AProps { ... }

export class A extends React.Component<AProps & myHocProps> {
    ...
}

export default myHoc(A);
```

*B.tsx*

```
import { AProps } from './A';  // WHY?
import withSearch, {
    Props,  // WHY?
    State,  // WHY?
    myHocProps } from './myHoc';
...

export interface BProps { ... }

export class  extends React.Component<BProps & myHocProps> {
    ...
}

export default myHoc(B);
```

Comment: `myHocProps` is missing

Comment: Added `myHocProps`. They are in `myHoc.tsx`. Thanks.

Comment: What I am seeing is you are creating a cycle by importing BProps inside AProps and AProps inside BProps. I assume the errors you see about the private names happen when you import AProps -> BProps -> AProps

Comment: @AlexanderVitanov But if I remove either or both I get the TS4082 errors written in my question. So what should I do?

Comment: While your approach is strange (the HOC should use generics to get the actual props of the component passed not hardcode all possible props) I am unable to reproduce your problem, removed all WHY imports and it still works ..